# SQL - Group By not working in this code

Tags: sql, ms-access

```
TRANSFORM Count(Details.Customer_ID) AS CountOfCustomer_ID
SELECT
  Switch(
    [Age] < 25,                  "Under 25",
    [Age] >= 25 And [Age] <= 32, "Between 25 And 32",
    [Age] >= 32 And [Age] <= 40, "Between 32 And 40",
    [Age] >= 40 And [Age] <= 45, "Between 40 And 45",
    [Age] > 45,                  "Over 45"
  ) AS Age_Range
FROM Details
  INNER JOIN [Account Status] ON Details.Customer_ID = [Account Status].Customer_ID
WHERE ((([Account Status].Account_Status)='Active'))
GROUP BY Details.Age, [Account Status].Account_Status
PIVOT Details.site;
```

My results are counting Active accounts like this:

```
Age Range          Site 1  Site 2  Site 3
-----------------  ------  ------  ------
Under 25                   1
Under 25                   1
Between 25 And 32                  1
Between 25 And 32                  1
Between 25 And 32                  1
Between 25 And 32                  1
```

When it should be like this:

```
Age Range          Site 1  Site 2  Site 3
-----------------  ------  ------  ------
Under 25                   2
Between 25 And 32                  4
```

I have tried grouping by the Switch statement as well and it does not work. Please help.

Comment: I think you should remove [Account Status] from the Group By

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't work either. This is really a pain, I can't figure it out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answers given by other's are correct in concept. Here's the SQL you can use that will work

```
TRANSFORM Count(Details.Customer_ID) AS CountOfCustomer_ID
SELECT Switch(
        [Age] < 25,                  "Under 25",
        [Age] >= 25 And [Age] <= 32, "Between 25 And 32",
        [Age] >= 32 And [Age] <= 40, "Between 32 And 40",
        [Age] >= 40 And [Age] <= 45, "Between 40 And 45",
        [Age] > 45,                  "Over 45"
      ) AS Age_Range
FROM   details 
       INNER JOIN [Account Status] 
         ON details.customer_id = [Account Status].customer_id 
WHERE  (( ( [Account Status].account_status ) = 'Active' )) 
GROUP  BY Switch(
        [Age] < 25,                  "Under 25",
        [Age] >= 25 And [Age] <= 32, "Between 25 And 32",
        [Age] >= 32 And [Age] <= 40, "Between 32 And 40",
        [Age] >= 40 And [Age] <= 45, "Between 40 And 45",
        [Age] > 45,                  "Over 45"
      )
PIVOT Details.site;
```

If you want to simplify things using an inline query this is what will work

```
TRANSFORM Count(Customer_ID) AS CountOfCustomer_ID
SELECT 
    Age_range 
 FROM 
(
SELECT Switch(
        [Age] < 25,                  "Under 25",
        [Age] >= 25 And [Age] <= 32, "Between 25 And 32",
        [Age] >= 32 And [Age] <= 40, "Between 32 And 40",
        [Age] >= 40 And [Age] <= 45, "Between 40 And 45",
        [Age] > 45,                  "Over 45"
      ) AS Age_Range, details.customer_id , details.site
FROM   details 
       INNER JOIN [Account Status] 
         ON details.customer_id = [Account Status].customer_id 
WHERE  (( ( [Account Status].account_status ) = 'Active' )) ) t
GROUP BY Age_range

PIVOT site;
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
GROUP BY Age_Range
```

Comment: Yes, Access gives me an error message that says "Age_Range is not a recognized field or expression." I don't know why though

Comment: The problem is a SQL's SELECT statement is the last thing to be applied. So when the command is being run, the GROUP BY will be hit before the SELECT and Age_Range hasn't yet been defined (since it's defined int the SELECT statement.

Answer (score 0):

When you `GROUP BY Details.Age`, the results will be grouped together BEFORE the `SELECT` statement is run. So you're not really grouping on what you think you are. Instead, it's grouping on the original ages.

So where you'd want 18, 19, and 21 to be grouped together, they're actually being grouped into their own separate groups.

You're going to have to get the Age_Range before the `GROUP BY`....maybe in a nested `SELECT` statement in the `FROM`?

```
SELECT a.Age_Range, COUNT(*)
FROM
    (TRANSFORM Count(Details.Customer_ID) AS CountOfCustomer_ID
    SELECT
      Switch(
        [Age] < 25,                  "Under 25",
        [Age] >= 25 And [Age] <= 32, "Between 25 And 32",
        [Age] >= 32 And [Age] <= 40, "Between 32 And 40",
        [Age] >= 40 And [Age] <= 45, "Between 40 And 45",
        [Age] > 45,                  "Over 45"
      ) AS Age_Range
    FROM Details
      INNER JOIN [Account Status] ON Details.Customer_ID = [Account Status].Customer_ID
    WHERE ((([Account Status].Account_Status)='Active'))
    PIVOT Details.site) a
GROUP BY a.Age_Range
```

Sorry, I've never used `TRANSFORM` or `PIVOT` so I'm not sure how that will work. But you can see the idea. The nested `SELECT` grabs your original results, then the outer `SELECT` does the `GROUP BY`.

Comment: That's correct -- Jerry, the ages in your table are probably all distinct so you are getting one row per age. To verify that Dirk is right, try your original code on a table that has ages 19, 21, 21, 26, 26, 28, 29. You'll see some 1's and 2's in your counts.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I'd like to point out your range conditions are incorrect, they overlap.

The ranges you defined will result in someone aged 32 or 40 falling in to more than one range:

```
[Age] >= 25 And [Age] <= 32, "Between 25 And 32",
[Age] >= 32 And [Age] <= 40, "Between 32 And 40",
[Age] >= 40 And [Age] <= 45, "Between 40 And 45",
```

The ranges need to be:

```
[Age] >= 25 And [Age] <= 32, "Between 25 And 32",
[Age] > 32 And [Age] <= 40, "Between 33 And 40",
[Age] > 40 And [Age] <= 45, "Between 41 And 45",
```

**DISCLAIMER:** I do not have MS Access, only SQL Server, which means the `TRANSFORM` operation is not available to me. I'm posting this answer to demonstrate another way of getting the result you want without the `SWITCH` statement.

Instead of using the `SWITCH` statement, create an age range lookup table; this also has the benefit of being easier to update should your age ranges change.

```
CREATE TABLE Age_Ranges
(
    age_range_name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    age_lower TINYINT NOT NULL,
    age_upper TINYINT NOT NULL
)

INSERT Age_Ranges(age_range_name, age_lower, age_upper) VALUES ('Under 25', 0, 24)
INSERT Age_Ranges(age_range_name, age_lower, age_upper) VALUES ('Between 25 And 32', 25, 32)
INSERT Age_Ranges(age_range_name, age_lower, age_upper) VALUES ('Between 33 And 40', 33, 40)
INSERT Age_Ranges(age_range_name, age_lower, age_upper) VALUES ('Between 41 And 45', 41, 45)
INSERT Age_Ranges(age_range_name, age_lower, age_upper) VALUES ('Over 45', 46, 120)
INSERT Age_Ranges(age_range_name, age_lower, age_upper) VALUES ('Error! Bad age data', 121, 255)
```

As I cannot use the `TRANSFORM` statement I created a matrix table to perform the transformation.

```
CREATE TABLE Site_Matrix
(
    site_nbr TINYINT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY ,
    site_1 TINYINT DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    site_2 TINYINT DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    site_3 TINYINT DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL
)

INSERT Site_Matrix(site_nbr,site_1) VALUES(1,1)
INSERT Site_Matrix(site_nbr,site_2) VALUES(2,1)
INSERT Site_Matrix(site_nbr,site_3) VALUES(3,1)
```

Finally, some customer test data.

```
CREATE TABLE Customer_Details
(
    customer_id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    customer_age TINYINT DEFAULT 255 NOT NULL,
    customer_site tinyint DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL
)

INSERT Customer_Details(customer_id, customer_age, customer_site) VALUES(1, 18, 2)
INSERT Customer_Details(customer_id, customer_age, customer_site) VALUES(2, 19, 2)
INSERT Customer_Details(customer_id, customer_age, customer_site) VALUES(3, 25, 3)
INSERT Customer_Details(customer_id, customer_age, customer_site) VALUES(4, 27, 3)
INSERT Customer_Details(customer_id, customer_age, customer_site) VALUES(5, 29, 3)
INSERT Customer_Details(customer_id, customer_age, customer_site) VALUES(6, 32, 3)
```

Using these tables you can get the result you want with this query. I've left out the join to account status as it's not necessary to demonstrate this method:

```
SELECT age_range_name, 
       SUM(site_1) AS site_1,
       SUM(site_2) AS site_2,
       SUM(site_3) AS site_3
FROM Customer_Details INNER JOIN Age_Ranges
    ON customer_age BETWEEN age_lower AND age_upper, Site_Matrix
WHERE customer_site = site_nbr
GROUP BY age_range_name
```

Query output:

```
age_range_name     site_1  site_2  site_3
Between 25 And 32  0       0       4
Under 25           0       2       0
```

I'm sure the SQL will require changes to work in Access, sorry about that, but I hope this gives you some ideas to solve your problem.

Comment: Practically none of the SQL works in Access. -1 for wasting people's time.

Comment: @David - I posted my answer after Conrad's had been accepted and was only trying to show the use of lookup tables as an alternative to using a SWITCH statement. I did say "I do not have MS Access, only SQL Server ... I'm posting this answer to demonstrate another way of getting the result you want without the SWITCH statement." and at the end I also said "I'm sure the SQL will require changes to work in Access", so I wasn't expecting people to cut-and-paste the SQL but understand the concept. I'm sorry if you found that to be a waste of your time.

Comment: It's not just details of SQL dialect that cause your solution to not be able to be ported to Access.